# Dom XML parser, detecting elements in text

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am looking for a way to parse out elements that are within text.

For example I have the following xml

```
<Elem1>

    <Elem1.1>{some text} <newLine/> {some text}</Elem1.1>

</Elem1>
```

so I can get to the Elem1.1 element, but when i call .getTextContent() on the node, I get back from it {some text}{some text} (so the  tag has basically been removed).

How do I get that new line such that I can replace it with a \n in the json object I am parsing out of this xml?

This is basically what I have right now

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Elem1");
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

    NodeList nodeList2 = ((Element)node).getElementsNyTagName("Elem1.1");


    for(int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {
        Element elem11 = (Element)nodeList2.item(j);
        // Add elem11.getTextContent() to an object and later use GSON to convert to Json string and save to file
    }
}
```

Thanks,
DMan

Comment: If the <newLine/> has been added to insert \n in the xml text, try replacing it with "&#xD;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `getTextContent()` (that's probably obvious).  just process the child nodes using normal dom traversal.  collect the text nodes and convert the other elements as you encounter them, combining everything into a single  StringBuilder.

Comment: Figured that's what I would have to do, just was thinking there might have been a different way. Thanks DMan

Answer (score -1):

.getTextContent() gives only text content of the element and its children. If you want the xml content, You can transform element back to xml and write out as string. Sample code..

```
NodeList nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName("Elem1");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    NodeList nodeList2 = ((Element)node).getElementsByTagName("Elem1.1");
    for(int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {
        Element elem11 = (Element)nodeList2.item(j);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(elem11);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString.substring("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".length()));
        // Add elem11.getTextContent() to an object and later use GSON to convert to Json string and save to file
    }
}
```

Comment: how will this help?  OP needs to get the `<newline/>` element and convert to a newline.

Comment: Basically this is for more than newline tag. My solution gives full xml content of the Node. After that you can replace the tags of your interest with a simple string replace.

Comment: why would converting it back from DOM to a string and doing a string replace be a better solution than just using the DOM in the first place?

Comment: Who said it is a better solution? This is just one way to do it, if you don't want to write code traverse DOM.

Comment: k, so this is a way to do it, but you wouldn't actually recommend it?